# URL Rewriting Problem

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my URL's subdomain.

http://**username**.domain.com >>> http://www.domain.com/user.php?u=**username**

I'm using this for my *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule .* /user.php?u=%1 [L]
```

Can you help me for debugging this problem ?

(Username's can contain a-z 0-9 and hypens)
*Also if subdomain is **www** or **api**, don't redirect them*

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user.php?u=%1 [L]
```

I have the same use case and its working for me

**EDIT:**

Add this to your httpd.conf file and try debugging

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteLog "F:/wamp/www/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
</IfModule>
```

Comment: try putting whole web address in last line e.g. `http://domain.com/user.php?u-%1 [L]`

Comment: i'm on shared server because of this i can't edit httpd.conf file . Also, i'm using wordpress and wordpress' url rewriting very well.